# JSDoc prototype as param

Tags: generics, phpstorm, webstorm, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I am using PhpStorm/WebStorm. I wonder if JSDoc is possible to document a method accepting a prototype and will return an instance of that prototype?

i.e.:

```
/**
 * @param {prototype<T>} Model
 * @param {Object} props
 * @return {T} a new instance
 * @template {T}
 */
function create(Model, props) {
    return new Model(props);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Generic-Types (the last example seems to be similar to your case)

Do you encounter any issues with it in the IDE?

Comment: do you mean the example `identity = function(a) { return a; }`? That one works in PhpStorm. However in my case the `T` should be `Model` itself instead of the prototype of `Model`. If Model is a class, then `T` will resolve to `(class {}).__proto__` which is `ƒ () { [native code] }`, instead of `Model.prototype`.